# How can I modify parameters within a file.txt from java through the FileOutputStream?

Tags: java

The issue is that, I have a file.txt that I changed the extension to file.properties precisely to manipulate it within the application.

Through FileInputStream I can consult them like this:

```
public static Properties config = new Properties();
public static InputStream configInput = null;
public static OutputStream configOutput = null;

try{
/*file.properties es el nombre del archivo ubicado en:
C:\Users\Gerencia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LectorParametros
*/
        configInput = new FileInputStream("configuracion.properties");
        config.load(configInput);
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("usuario"));
        System.out.println(config.getProperty("clave"));
    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error LEYENDO configuración\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I have tried with FileOutputStream :

```
try{
            configOutput = new FileOutputStream("configuracion.properties");
            config.setProperty("clave", "123456");
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error MODIFICANDO configuración\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

But what it does is modify all the content of "configuracion.properties"
What i can do?
Thanks

Comment: *"What i can do?"* Some *research*, e.g. **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), and ye shall find the method `save()`, which is the *opposite* of `load()`, and it'll tell ye to use the method **`store(...)`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply miss the store method. Here is the code (stripping exception management).

```
configOutput = new FileOutputStream("configuracion.properties");
config.setProperty("clave", "123456");
config.store(configOutput, "Your comment here");
```